# imprimir valores de un for en python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

tengo este codigo

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from urllib.request import urlopen

from urllib.error import HTTPError

from urllib.error import URLError

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import subprocess
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from time import sleep
# try:
print ('abriendo chrome')
contador=0
data = []
print ('obteniendo datos...')
print ('porfavor espere')

try:
    page = ''

except HTTPError as e:

    print (e)
except URLError:

    print ('Server down or incorrect domain')
else:
        opts = Options()
        opts.headless = False
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
        driver.get(page)
        especialidad = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='info_nuestros_medicos']").find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")
        nombre = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/ul")
        lugar = 'Viña del Mar'

        for especialidadsita,nombresito in zip(especialidad,nombre):
            print(especialidadsita.text)
            print(nombresito.text.replace(especialidadsita.text,''))

        '''data.append({"data":lugarsito.text})
with open('inmunomedica.json', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
 json.dump(data, f,indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
 driver.close()
 print("Runing php script")
 subprocess.run(["php", "helper_launcher.php"])   '''
```

el cual me imprime la especialidad y solo un nombre del medico que esta en esa especialidad
lo que necesito es que me imprima la especialidad y los nombres que esten en esa especialidad
pero al ejecutar el codigo obtengo esto

```
  Acupuntura
- ROSAS HENRIQUEZ ALVARO
  Cardiología
- ROSENTOCK MEYER JOCHEN
```

el cual el medico que esta en cardiologia pertenece a acupuntura
en que me estoy equivocando?
me gustaria que quede algo como esto

```
Acupuntura
- ROSAS HENRIQUEZ ALVARO
- ROSENTOCK MEYER JOCHEN

Cardiología
- DÍAZ NAVARRO RIENZI
- MUÑOZ MORENO JOSÉ
- REBOLLEDO BERROETA HUGO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya pude hacer lo que necesitaba con un replace
publico el extracto de codigo para quien lo necesite

```
especialidad = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='info_nuestros_medicos']").find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")
        nombre = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/ul")
        lugar = 'Viña del Mar'

        for especialidadsita,nombresito in zip(especialidad,nombre):
            print(especialidadsita.text)
            print(nombresito.text.replace(especialidadsita.text,''))
```